# Why is my $(document).ready Not Firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an index.html file which looks like this (the rest is omitted),

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
    <li><a href="sync.html">Sync</a></li>
    <li><a href="list.html">List</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click on the list item called 'List' it takes me to list.html.

Inside list.html it includes this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        createDatabase(readFromDatabase);
    });

</script>
```

$(document).ready does not fire in this circumstance when I am redirected to list.html.

If I refresh index.html it then fires. As you can guess I would like it to fire every time. What is happening?

I am using jquery, jquerymobile, and also phonegap.

Comment: You'll need to include `$(document).ready(...)` on *every* page or include an external script that you reference from each of your pages.

Comment: I am including it in index.html, which is where I want it to fire, and it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, with jQuery Mobile, you should use the `pageinit` event instead of `$(document).ready()`. It is explained in the event section of the jQuery Mobile Documentation (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: I am using jquery as well as jquery mobile. Is that the correct thing to be doing? The reason I am using jquery and jquery mobile is that I am using a call to $.ajax() and am I correct in thinking that won't be in jquery mobile?

Comment: Just tried it, you are definately correct. I removed the reference to jquery mobile and it fired every time.

Comment: JQuery Mobile needs JQuery to work so you are free to use it. You should however use another event than $(document).ready() since it only triggers on your first page.

Comment: Had to fiddle around with things for a bit, but it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Heads-up: In version 1.4 of jQuery Mobile, [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) was deprecated in favor of [pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "$" with "jQuery".